# CakePHP list most common occurrence of value

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP (v3.X), how can you list the most common occurrences of a value in a table.

Example: In a `Users` table, list the 10 most common `first_name` values.

Something like this SQL but I expect you can do it in a more cakey way.

`select first_name, COUNT(first_name) AS MOST_FREQUENT from users GROUP BY first_name ORDER BY COUNT(first_name) DESC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$most_common = $this->Users->find()
  ->select(['first_name', 'count' => $query->func()->count('*')])
  ->group(['first_name'])
  ->order(['count' => 'DESC'])
  ->limit(10);
```

Read:

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data**

Comment: Yep that's the job. Not sure why it was flagged as too broad. You managed to answer it first answer, first time.

Comment: I edit my answer to add ```->limit(10)``` because you ask for first 10 results.  Don't know why is your question flaged. You can accept answer.